# jQuery find element by index and insert node after it

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with this little conundrum, I've tried doing it in the shortest hand possible but I'm not sure if insertAfter works this way.

Can anyone suggest a working way of doing this.

I have made a fiddle of my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/GzHnj/3/

I am simply trying to insert another custom `li` after the 5th `li`. But trying to do it in the most efficient way.

```
$('<li style="background: red"></li>').insertAfter( $('li').index(4) );
```

Can anyone help me with this please, thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be confusing [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). Use this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/GzHnj/4/)**

```
$('<li style="background: red"></li>').insertAfter( $('li:eq(4)') );
```

Comment: `.insertAfter( $('li:eq(4)') );` could be `.insertAfter('li:eq(4)');` no second jQuery-call needed. ;)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Another new bit of jquery, thanks for showing :-)